# Stirling number second kind, $S(n, n-3) = \frac{n(n-1)(n-2)^2(n-3)^2}{48}$

Tags: combinatorics, stirling-numbers

How to prove, that $S(n, n-3) = \frac{n(n-1)(n-2)^2(n-3)^2}{48}$.

I want to go the combinatoric way. I've already seen this question ( [Find a closed formula for the stirling number $S(n, n-3)$ for n $\ge$ $3$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/284816/find-a-closed-formula-for-the-stirling-number-sn-n-3-for-n-ge-3) ) but I don't understand it.

It's clear, that there are...

1. case:  4 elements in the first box
2. case: 3 elements in the first box, 2 in the second
3. case: 2 elements in the first box, 2 in the second and 2 in the third.

It's clear to me that 1. case is $\binom{n}{4}$, but why is for example the 3. case $\frac{1}{6} \binom{n}{2} \binom{n-2}{2} \binom{n-4}{2}$ ?? Where does the $\frac{1}{6}$ come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

${n \brace m}$ represents the number of ways to partition the set $\{1,2,\cdots,n\}$ into $m$ subsets.
Now you have to pay attention to the fact that the order of the sub-sets does not count, i.e. that the sub-sets are themselves arranged into a set.
Then when you have $2, 3, 4,\ldots $ subsets with the same size, you have to divide by the factorial of their number.  Same, if you have $n_a$ subsets with size $a$, $n_b$ with size $b$, etc. you shall divide by $n_a! n_b! \ldots$.

So the $6 = 3!$ comes from the correction on having $3$ subsets of same size.

Comment: Thanks! And for case 2 it's 1/2?

Comment: Oh, I think I misinterpreted your answer. For case 2 there is no need to divide cause the size of the subsets are different, right?

Comment: yes that's right , or also you might think that you shall divide by $1! \cdot 1! \cdots$

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 2):

The boxes are unmarked, so (12)(34)(56) is the same as (34)(12)56). So, you have to divide by $6=3!.$